# Laravel relationship between two tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

I'd like your input on this.

I have a `Customer_table` with a field `name`. I have another table called `Reservation_table` with a `Customer_name` field.

How can I relate them in such a way that I'd see all the bookings by the specific customer?

Comment: It will be very much easier if you follow Laravel's naming convention when designing your database.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/laravel-table-names-are-plural-by-default

Answer (score 0):

In `Reservation_table` you should have a field(foreign key) `userid` in order ta have a user for each reservation.

Answer (score 0):

You can using primary key - foreign key relationship to relate/join those two tables. Also, instead of having a 'Customer_name' field as your FK referring to 'name' field in 'Customer_table' table, it is better to have an id (unique) generated for each customer; This way you can have an efficient way of uniquely identifying and relating customer across tables; can save space on Database side as well. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already set the foreign keys. But why can't I use Laravel Eloquent relationship as well? I'm very new to Laravel

Comment: this will help you https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use eloquent you must first define a relationship.
One reservation belongs to a user. Here is how to define the relationships:
Inside the Reservation model:

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App/User'); //User model
}
```

To define the inverse you do the following:
Inside User model:

```
public function reservations()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App/Reservation'); // Reservation Model
}
```

Now you can do the following in your controller:

```
$reservations = Auth::user()->reservations;
```

Now you have all reservations by the currently logged in user.
I am not sure if I got the question right so ask away.

Comment: @SaiKrishna did you try it out? This the Eloquent way of doing it.